# Retreive data from firebase methodwise

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I retrieve data from firebase for 2 different constructors? Here is my Eggs class. I want to receive only laying for one and hatching and status for another.

```
private String laying, hatching,status;

public Eggs() {
}
public  Eggs(String laying)
{
    this.laying=laying;
}
public Eggs(String hatching, String status) {
    this.hatching = hatching;
    this.status = status;
}
```

I use this method to retrieve data from firebase

```
         public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {      
                for (DataSnapshot breedingSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Eggs data = breedingSnap.getValue(Eggs.class);
                    eg.add(data);
                }            
            });
```

How can I implement something like this-

```
Eggs laying=new Eggs(String laying);
Eggs st=new Eggs(String hatching,String status);
```

then add them to the arraylist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) passed to onDataChange to reach the relevant child snapshots using [child()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#child(java.lang.String)), read them out using [getValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue()), and pass them to your constructor.

The documentation for getValue() says:

> getValue() returns the data contained in this snapshot as native
>   types. The possible types returned are:
>
> - Boolean
> - String
> - Long
> - Double
> - Map
> - List
>
> This list is recursive; the possible types for Object in the above list is given by the same list. These types correspond to the types available in JSON.

For example, to read a string child value called "laying" out of the snapshot:

```
DataSnapshot layingSnapshot = breedingSnap.child("laying");
String laying = (String) layingSnapshot.getValue();
```

So, you will have to both know the names of the children to read, and also check and cast their expected types.  To avoid runtime problems, you should also check the type of the child value before casting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Eggs {
    @Nullable
    private String laying;
    @Nullable
    private String hatching;
    @Nullable
    private String status;

    public String getLaying() {
        return laying;
    }

    public void setLaying(String laying) {
        this.laying = laying;
    }

    public String getHatching() {
        return hatching;
    }

    public void setHatching(String hatching) {
        this.hatching = hatching;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```